# JavaScript to change field color based on its value

Tags: javascript, field, acrobat

Can't get JavaScript script to work.

I have a pdf with 18 questions and those questions have 4 choices to select with radio buttons.
The code for the radio buttons work fine and will total to a field at the end of the form called "score".
I have the below code in the "score" field using the validation tab in Adobe.

```
var fm = this.getField("score").value;
if (fm >= 1 && fm <= 26)
  event.target.fillColor = (0.537, 0.776, 0); //fill color red  
else if (fm >= 27 && fm <= 48)
  event.target.fillColor = (1, 0.804, 0.623); //fill color orange  
else if (fm >= 49 && fm <= 62)
  event.target.fillColor = (1, 0, 0.709); //fill color yellow
else if (fm >= 63 && fm <= 72)
  event.target.fillColor = (1, 1, 1); // fill color green
else
  event.target.fillColor = (1, 1, 1);
```

What am I doing wrong? Should this code be in the 'Global' section?
Please help.

Comment: _"using the validation tab in Adobe"_ Adobe what? Adobe is the name of a company!

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ No idea, you haven't told us what is not working, nor describe how it's not working. What _should_ this code do?

Comment: Code like `(0.538, 0.776, 0)` will result in `0`. You can't group values in javascript with `()`, see [comma operator[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It's unclear what you are using, but you should either use an array or a proper string format depending on what the documentation says. I've checked the documentation of acrobat (if that's what you are using) and it turns out that you should use an array like: `['RGB', 0.537, 0.776, 0]`

Comment: phuzi, I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro. Have a bunch of option buttons that when selected result in a value that total in a field labeled 'score'. I wan the fill color of the 'score' field to change colors based on the value of the field.

Comment: Konrad, I changed all the ( ) to brackets [ ] and the field still will not change colors. I also tried using the true RGB colors, red - 255,0,0, and the field won't change color.

Comment: I found [a similar post on the Adobe Support forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/javascript-change-fill-colour-depending-on-the-value-in-the-field/td-p/9065115) which uses array values to set colours. So `(0.537, 0.776, 0)` should probably be `["RGB", 0.537, 0.776, 0]` (I don't think that's going to be red though).

Answer (score 0):

The color definitions you are using are not valid in Acrobat JavaScript.

You might have a closer look at the documentation (which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, downloadable from the developer section of the Adobe website.

The correct color definition is an array, and it looks like what is mentioned in some comments (such as `['RGB', 0.537, 0.776, 0]`).

In addition to that, I would suggest to put the colorising code into the Format event of the `score` field. You then will address its value as event.value (instead of field value). So, the first line would look like

```
var fm = event.value ;
```

With that, the code should work (note: I have not verified it).

Comment: See my answer in that topic.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I did change the ( ) to [ ] and change the first line to var fm = event.value; and everything is working great!